# Defining a list and range of \ang values in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

The angle processing function `\ang` provided in `siunitx` 
to print angles are printed in arc format with degree, arcmin and arcsec separated by semi-colons:

```
\ang{1;2;3}
```

Is it possible to define a macro for lists and ranges of angular quantities in a similar way as the `\SIlist` and `\SIrange` functions to handle lists and ranges of numbers?

Comment: Please clarify, how this list should look like. As `\ang` and `\SIlist` both use a semicolon as separator, you should choose your preferred syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Here is something to start with:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\angRange{O{} m m}{\SIrange[parse-numbers=false, #1]{\ang[parse-numbers=true]{#2}}{\ang[parse-numbers=true]{#3}}{}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \angRange{2.67}{6;7;6.5} \\
    \angRange[number-angle-product = \,]{2.67}{6;7;6.5} \\
    \angRange{6;7;6.5}{-1;;} \\
    \angRange[arc-separator = \,]{6;7;6.5}{-1;;} \\   
    \angRange{-1;;}{;;-3} \\
    \sisetup{add-arc-degree-zero}
    \angRange{-1;;}{;;-3} \\
    \sisetup{add-arc-minute-zero}
    \angRange{-1;;}{;;-3} \\
    \sisetup{add-arc-second-zero}
    \angRange{-1;;}{;;-3} \\
    \angRange{45.697}{6;7;6.5} \\
    \angRange[angle-symbol-over-decimal]{45.697}{6;7;6.5} \\
    \angRange{2}{4} \\
    \angRange[range-units = brackets]{2}{4} \\
    %\angRange[range-units = repeat][]{2}{4} \\ % should not be used as it makes no sense here
    %\angRange[range-units = single][]{2}{4}\\ % should not be used as it makes no sense here
    \SIrange[range-units = single]{2}{4}{\degree}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is `arara`?

Comment: "Good  question! arara is  a  TEX  automation  tool  based  on  rules  and  directives.  It is, in some aspects, similar to other well-known tools like latexmk and rubber. The key difference (and probably the selling point) might be the fact that arara aims at explicit instructions in the source code (in the form of comments) in order to determine what to do instead of relying on other resources, such as log file analysis. It is a different approach for an automation tool, and we have both advantages and disadvantages of such design." From the manual